# Ubuntu one restarts sync every 5 min

Tags: ubuntu-one

I've looked around the site, there seems to be a lot of people who are having issues with Ubuntu One syncing. My problem is a bit different, as the sync keeps on restarting on my computer every 5 min, and every time time I get this message:

'refDenver.pdf' is being uploaded to your cloud.

The file is small, and I've been waiting fro an hours now already and it keeps repeating the message. What could be the problem of that?

Thanks in advance,
Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up your account and see that your account is on the server that was experiencing high loads the past few days. We have this under better control now and file sync performance should be much better, including your small file being synced successfully rather than the sync continually being reset.

Answer (score 1):

***Workaround***: I've had a very similar experience to this one.  I was able to complete the transfer by removing my wireless network from the equation and connecting a cable directly to my router.

See [Ubuntu One Upload Restarts](https://askubuntu.com/q/56900/23216)

Best of luck,
Adam.