# Ubuntu One Upload Restarts

Tags: ubuntu-one

I'm having some trouble with Ubuntu One.

I'm trying to upload a file to Ubuntu One for the first time and the transfer always starts again from the beginning.
The file is about 500MB and Ubuntu One gets to 800KB - 1.5MB before it restarts the transfer mysteriously.
I'm using the command `u1sdtool --current-transfers` to indicate how much of the transfer is completed.
I've tried `u1sdtool --status` and it doesn't show any errors or problems.

I'm on a wireless network and I will try a wired connection but I was under the impression that Ubuntu One handled network re-connections so I thought this might be worth looking into regardless.

If anyone has any suggestions on how I can identify why it is restarting that would be great.

Also, if it helps my account is UBCToad and this problem appears to be very similar to [Ubuntu one restarts sync every 5 min](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43520/ubuntu-one-restarts-sync-every-5-min/43944#43944).

Answer (score 2):

OP answered his own question:

After connecting a cable to my router the file transfer completed successfully on the first attempt.

This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I had to stop service `u1sdtool --quit` and restart it with `u1sdtool --start`. Then synced again.

Hope it helps